# Has anybody ever implemented a rails-like functionality for different layouts in ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

i'm looking for an implementation for different layout files in emberjs like rails does.
for example having an "application_layout.hbs" for the main app and a different one for the login page. "login_layout.hbs" for example.

Comment: did you have a look at this: https://github.com/ghempton/ember-layout it's a little bit out of date I guess, but still worth mentioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not implemented it myself, but this is maybe what you are looking for, is taken from the [ember source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L617)

> Views can have a secondary template that wraps their main template. Like
>     primary templates, layouts can be any function that  accepts an optional
>     context parameter and returns a string of HTML that will be inserted inside
>     view's tag. Views whose HTML element is self closing (e.g. `<input />`)
>     cannot have a layout and this property will be ignored. 
>     Most typically in Ember a layout will be a compiled `Ember.Handlebars`
>     template. A view's layout can be set directly with the `layout` property or reference
>     an existing Handlebars template by name with the `layoutName` property.
>     A template used as a layout must contain a single use of the Handlebars
>     `{{yield}}` helper. The HTML contents of a view's rendered `template` will be
>     inserted at this location:

**JS**

```
AViewWithLayout = Ember.View.extend({
  layout: Ember.Handlebars.compile("<div class='my-decorative-class'>{{yield}}</div>")
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("I got wrapped"),
});
```

hope it helps